# How to convert ton force to pound force, manual pellet press

Tags: pressure

I'm looking into manual pellet presses and the one in mind lists a 12T clamping force and then goes on to detail that the analogue gauge goes from 0- 24,000 lbs. Are these two numbers related? When I try to convert T to lbs I usually get 26,880 lbs for 12T.

Thanks!

Comment: which tons are you using? Ton-force (short) converts to 24,000 lbs

Comment: Ah, I had been using Ton-force (long)...** face palm **
Thanks a lot Solar Mike!

Answer (score 1):

Since tons are being related to pounds, you should not start by assuming metric tons.  A ton = 2000 pounds, so 12 tons would be 24,000 pounds.

Comment: What took you so long? We had this covered a bit ago.

Comment: @Sol: Not sure what you mean.  Looks like I answered this only 3 hours after the question was posted.  It was the first, and at this writing still the only answer.

Comment: But the comment that gave the solution to the OP was posted 5 hours ago, perhaps giving you sufficient time to read it.

Comment: @Sol: Comments aren't answers.  Learn how the site works.  I wrote a actual *answer*, since nobody else had.

Comment: I need to start trawling the comments then to garner more points... perhaps my ethics hold me back.

Comment: Proper site use != what seems intuitively "correct".

Comment: @Mark yes, I thought I had operated "correctly", I was just pleased that the OP had a solution to his problem - some of us just want to help. I will have to post answers and not help via the comments...

Answer (score 1):

Which tons are you using? Ton-force (short) converts to 24,000 lbs – Solar Mike 5 hours ago

Posted this as an answer, having had it confirmed by the OP as helping him with his issue, confirmed by his comment : 
Ah, I had been using Ton-force (long)...** face palm ** Thanks a lot Solar Mike!